# flash component appear out of box

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

After embedded flash content on HTML, I tried to click comboxbox list, it was appear to be truncated, how do I actually make the list visible outside the flash content? Seeing some of the commercial ads with out-of-box feature, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

hi you should use this in your object code

```
<PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent>
```

and find the embed and add this

```
wmode="transparent"
```

try this